Diff-in-diff with an unbalanced panel
Say I want to study the effect of some intervention using a diff-in-diff setup. I have a panel of units observed during some period. I can identify treated/non-treated groups and pre/post periods (assume it's a classic DID, with no staggered interventions etc). My problem is that I have unbalanced panels - for some units, also those treated, I don't have full observations in the post period. I could estimate a DID model on the balanced sample only or simply disregard the fact that panel is unbalanced (I guess it's not a problem for Stata xtdidrgress), but I'm afraid it may create biased results. It may happen that units are dropped from the sample as a result of the treatment. For example, if I studied the impact of some medical treatment on blood pressure, it could happen that due to treatment blood pressure of some patients falls and they stop visiting doctor, and that's why there are no observations for them.
What should I do in such a case?

With this kind of attrition, the bias will make the effect less negative, making the medication seem less effective at lowering BP. If the effect remains significant, you can say that with this kind of selection, your effect is a lower bound on the ATET. This assumes you know the mechanism behind the attrition.
I suspect balancing the panel or ignoring attrition will give you similarly biased estimates since balancing only alters $\bar Y(post=1,treated=1)$ a bit, while the three other means remain the same as when you ignore it.
If there are dosage variations in the treatment group, and the problem arises mainly with large doses, you can try to extrapolate the missing BPs from the dosage-effect curve from continuous treatment DID. In general, a model for attrition could help here.
There are also bounding/imputation sensitivity checks you can do. For example, you can assume the missing BP is the initial value plus the time trend (the coefficient on post), i.e., zero effect for fainters. You can also back out how negative the effect has to get for the fainters to make the overall DID effect become insignificant. You can even use the BP threshold that makes people faint if you have that estimate from another study.
